# Compiled JavaScript Files Not Appearing In Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I'm using TypeScript 0.9.5 and when I add a TypeScript file, I no longer see the compiled JavaScript file or the generated source maps in Visual Studio solution explorer.

Where have my JavaScript files gone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the generated files are like binaries, they shouldn't really be part of your project or be added to source control.

In previous versions of TypeScript, having the files in the project / under source control could cause issues on build servers in cases where the build server was averse to changing files that are under source control.

Another problem caused by having the files in the project / under source control is that even if you don't change your TypeScript file, the generated files are re-created on build and are picked up by source control clients as being changes. These would all show as revisions if you checked them in (or you'd have to manually exclude the changes to avoid polluting your source control repository).

The new treatment of the generated files makes them more like your .NET DLLs - they get generated on the build server (and locally on your disk) but you don't need them in source-control.

Comment: It would be nice if there was an easy way to view the side/side TS/JS like there was in previous versions. Having it auto nested was also nice. Seems like it is getting harder to use TS instead of easier.

Comment: My workflow is having the whole folder (ts/js) included in visual studio using a glob. However the JS files are not checked into source control. Basically treat these as different : "files in the project / under source control"

Answer (score 0):

click on show more in solution Explorer as shown in picture

[click here to see image..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZGZd.png)